# Anaconda Installed MATPLOTLIB Not Recognized by IDLE SHELL

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I had installed Anaconda and it had already been embedded with some packages like matplotlib.

But in my python idle shell, if I type in "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" it returns No module named 'matplotlib'

I assume the path directory where python calls in matplolib is different from where anaconda installed it.

Any hint to solve this situation?

Comment: Is your python IDLE connected to the right python interpreter? Maybe its using a second python installed beside anaconda. If it's spyder you can check this in the preferences tab 'python interpreter'. In Pycharm you can find it in your preferences Settings/Preferences in ProjectInterpreter.

Comment: What happens if you type 'conda list'? Is there a 'matplotlib' version?